# How do you preserve text from STDIN when you print to STDOUT?

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

I'm writing a chat program, and I'm running into an issue involving STDOUT and STDIN. Essentially, while a client is typing something out, if the client receives some text from the server, it "adds" to the cursor where the client is typing into. STDIN will only take the text that the client has typed, but how can I "neatly" print out what was received from the server to STDOUT without interrupting the flow of text that the client has already typed out (AKA, preserve STDIN while displaying STDOUT)?

I'm not sure if this explanation is the best, so I wrote up a small little program to illustrate the issue as best as I could. It reads from STDIN, exiting when the user types in 99, but I set up an alarm to interrupt the user's typing and print to STDOUT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

void alarm_handler(int dummy) {
    printf("INTERRUPTION !!! \n");
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    alarm(3);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char answer[1000];

    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    alarm(3);

    printf("Please enter 99: ");
    while(1){
        fgets(answer,1000,stdin);

        if(strcmp(answer,"99\n") == 0){
            printf("\nYou entered 99! bye!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("Please enter 99: ");
    }

    return 0; //exit(0);
}
```

The results are shown below; all I did was type a sentence. You can see how it gets interrupted five times.

```
Please enter 99: The quick brown foINTERRUPTION !!! 
x jumped over the lazyINTERRUPTION !!! 
 dog, but it still INTERRUPTION !!! 
likes to chaseINTERRUPTION !!! 
 the c......INTERRUPTION !!! 
^C
```

What I would like to do is to have something like the following:

```
INTERRUPTION !!! 
INTERRUPTION !!! 
INTERRUPTION !!! 
INTERRUPTION !!! 
INTERRUPTION !!! 
Please enter 99: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, but it still likes to chase the c......
^C
```

Is it possible to accomplish this, to preserve "uncommitted" text? I was thinking of ways to detect the text through something like polling for POLLIN on STDIN, but it seems that polling doesn't recognize it until the user types in a new line to send the text to STDIN.

EDIT: Sorry for the edit, but while libraries like curses appears to be an option, I was wondering if it was possible to accomplish this by using just C or something similar?

Comment: Look into the curses library for cursor position and control https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Thanks for that. It seems that others recommended the same thing, but I was wondering if it was possible to accomplish this without the use of TUI libraries, just using C? For instance, I tried working with '\r', the carriage return, but it overwrote what the user entered.

Comment: I think this is gonna be pretty hard to do given that you don't "know" what's been written to the screen when you're in the context of `alarm_handler` so you can't fix it if you dirty the screen, and `fgets` doesn't write stuff to a steady place.

Comment: stdout is not your terminal.  stdin is not your terminal.  Make sure you understand the difference

Comment: Of course, you *can* do it in C. Ncurses is not magic; it's ordinary C code and you can look at it if you want to. But it's a lot of work, and there's lots of corner cases which you will get wrong at first. We use libraries precisely to avoid doing unnecessary work. Be glad that someone did that for you.